# Ethereum: is validating wallet ownership possible?

Tags: token, ethereum, smartcontracts

How can I validate that somebody owns a wallet address?

Use Case:

- Wallet owner donates 10 ETH to the wallet address of a crowdfunding campaign
- Campaign decides to give perks (similar to kickstarter) AFTER the campaign has ended.
- If wallet owner who contributed is entitled to a perk, how could that owner claim that perk?  ideally they could provide a key that only the sender/receiver would know, but the campaign only has a transaction receipt and a wallet address which is all public knowledge.

Is this crowdunding camping going to need to launch a smart contract?

:-/

- 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While a smart contract may be a useful tool in the case above, the user that wants to prove that they control an address can sign a message using the private key associated with the address that the donation was sent funds to the campaign from.

The exchange would go similar to the following:

```
Organization: Hooray we raised our goal and we had the great idea to
give everyone that participated a free t-shirt! Send us a signed message with the
word 'shirt' and your address and we will mail you a shirt.
```

The user would then go to the wallet that controlled the address that they sent the transaction from and, using the address account, sign a message:

```
> personal.unlockAccount('0x30ddF5144a0483e3c1d6E5f45C396aC72a487B9e',
     'examplepassword',60);
true
> eth.sign(eth.accounts[41], web3.sha3("shirt 123 Main St., Any Town, Any Country"))
"0x90e8f95ca6f44410572401ad5d16255914a23af76613580c436926985dfdbfdb2d808a691cb808ed32cb0cc419d306916c17dd26a8df53bbbc31826352d81ca31b"
```

The user can then send the organization a message (via email, etc) with their ethereum address they used to send funds, the message they signed (in this case `shirt 123 Main St., Any Town, Any Country`) and the signature. The organization can then enter the three into an ethereum node for verification or use an online service like [Etherscan's verifySig](https://etherscan.io/verifySig) tool (the above demo is in Etherscan verifySig [here](https://etherscan.io/verifySig/23)).

Of course like you alluded to this would be possible through a smart contract. In return for sending funds to the contract, the end user could have functions that would allow them to redeem rewards even from a new contract that is generated after the original crowdsale contract is completed.

A smart contract may also be a good option since opensource contracts exist that implement multi-sig to extract funds from the contract and the contract can also control how much the organization raises at what rates.